# How do I create a longtable like shown?

Tags: longtable

I'm working on my thesis and need to create a table like this.
Could anyone provide me with a template?[image]

Currently, I have this

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{10cm}c|p{10cm}|c|p{10cm}c|p{10cm}}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Use Case} & \textbf{Values} & \textbf{Challenges} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
Use case name & a long text lorem ipsum a long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsum & a long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsuma long text lorem ipsum \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\end{longtable}
```

which leads to an ugly table that is not even fully visible on the page

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! What is it in particular with this table that you cannot reproduce? The brown blobs? It helps if you create a minimal example with what you have tried so far. And that you explain a bit more. Again, welcome!

Comment: @mickep Hi! I've updated the description to give a better idea of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Your example is not compiling. But we can see that you add 4 columns of 10 centimeters each. How wide is your page? Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: why have you declared 8 columns? no row has 8 entries, and is your page more than 40cm wide?

Comment: Please have a look (read) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options , maybe it can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please modify your code  to make it a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and compilable "as is" without having to guess  essential packages to read your table, margins,  page size or font size, for instance. Note four columns of 10 cm are obviously wrong for an A4 page, but they could be fine for a landscape A3 page, but without a crystal ball we cannot know if you are making a poster  or whatever else.